# Difference between embedded surfaces and immersed surface under mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

In 
*Huisken, Gerhard*, [**Asymptotic behavior for singularities of the mean curvature flow**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214444099), there is a conjecture  that the blow up rate of singularities of arbitrary embedded surfaces is same with convex surfaces.  (1)
$$
\text{blow up rate:  }~~~  \frac{1}{2(T-t)}\le \max_{M_t}|A|^2\le \frac{C_0}{2(T-t)} ~~~~~~~
$$

And Huisken explains it is not right for all immersed surfaces. Because the curvature of an immersed curve developing a cusp will blow up at a faster rate. (2)

First, about the explain (2), there is not a analytic explain , how to know it has a faster rate?

Second, I treat the embedding as immersion adding homeomorphism. Why the homeomorphism can  eliminate the situation in (2) ?